# Save env variable value not definition

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, github-actions

I'm working on a github actions workflow and have sent an environment variable:

```
env:
  rundate: $(date --date="2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')
```

If I check that in the terminal on local, I see what I need:

```
echo $(date --date="2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')
20220721
```

But, when trying to use in workflow, in this case to set the path of where to download an artifact to:

```
  - name: Download BQ data from previous job
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: bq-data
      path: _${{ env.rundate }}data.tsv
```

Expected/desired a path of `_20220721data.csv` but in the runner console I see:

```
/_"$(date --date="2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')"data.tsv
```

How can I set the env variable to be a string, the string in this case here and now being 20220721 as opposed to being the method of calculating the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the value of a variable to the result of executing a shell script. You can't do that in the `env` section of a github action, which can only have static values (or references to context values, like `${{ github.ref }}`). In this case, you're simply setting the value of `rundate` to the literal string `$(date --date="2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')`.

You can have a step emit your desired value as a labelled output using the [`set-output`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-setting-a-value) command, and then refer to those outputs in subsequent steps:

```
jobs:
  example:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - id: set_date
        run: |
          timestamp="$(date --date="2 days ago" '+%Y%m%d')"
          echo "::set-output name=timestamp::$timestamp"

      - name: Download BQ data from previous job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: bq-data
          path: _${{ steps.set_date.outputs.timestamp }}data.tsv
```

Comment: Note: editied for syntax and tested :)